# C - Given two arrays, how do you find the amount of unique elements of one of the arrays?

Tags: c, arrays

I have this code I've been working on that displays values of array1 that are duplicates of array2 and duplicates of other values in array1, but I've been having difficulties calculating the amount of unique values. [sizeOfA, sizeOfB, a[] and b[] are obtained through the main function]

```
int aDupes = 0;
int bDupes = 0;
int i, j, k;

for(i = 0; i < sizeOfA; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < sizeOfB; j++){
        if(a[i] == b[j]){
            bDupes++;
        }
    } 
} 
for(i = 0; i < sizeOfA; i++){
    for(j = i+1; j < sizeOfA; j++){
        for(k = 0; k < sizeOfB; k++){
            if(a[i] == a[j] && a[i] == b[k]){
                aDupes++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So for example
a[] = {1, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8}
b[] = {1, 3, 8, 2}
would return aDupes = 1 ; bDupes = 4. But the amount of unique elements should be 3 (5, 6, 7). How can I do this?

Comment: Also, if anyone can give advice on returning a dynamic array of these unique values I'd appreciate it very greatly. :)

Comment: You should search for and read about *set operations*. For the "unique" values search for *set difference*.

Comment: Subtract `aDupes` from `bDupes` you will get all the unique elements of array `a[]`

Answer (score 1):

```
int flag=0,unique=0;
for(i = 0; i < sizeOfA; i++){
for(j = i+1; j < sizeOfA; j++){
    for(k = 0; k < sizeOfB; k++){
        if(a[i] != a[j] && a[i] != b[k]){
            flag++;
        }
    }
 }
 if (flag==0){
     unique++;
  } 
 flag=0;
}
```

This `unique` variable will give the value of unique elements of the array `a`

Answer (score 0):

Use mapping, it is more easy and very clear to understand.

First map all the elements of array2 and check for array1 by also making the map of array 1 and so on.